# How to mark all instances of -1 in a dataframe as NA in r

Tags: r

I am currently trying to clean a dataframe for further machine learning analysis. I want to replace all the instances of -1 as null. I know how to do this by column, but how do I do this over a lot of columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume a dataframe containing 10 columns with 1 and -1:

```
DF <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1,-1), 1000, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10))
```

Then you simple replace the -1 values by NA:

```
DF[DF==-1] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your data is in a data frame.

```
df[df == -1] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is similar to the ones posted above, I thought of a small tweak.
I think you mean replace -1 with NAs, since missing values are stored as NAs in R.

Depending upon whether -1 is stored as a factor/character or a numeric variable, you could try -

```
dfx = data.frame(x = c(0,1,2,-1), y = c("a", "b", "c","-1") ) 

dfx[dfx == -1 | dfx == "-1"] <- NA
```